# How can I get Taylor expansion of $f(x) = \log(x+1)/(8!x)$ at $x=0?$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I need to compute higher order derivatives (7th 8th, 9th, 10th) evaluated at $x_0 = 0$ of function defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac1{8!} & x=0 \\ \frac{\log(x+1)}{8!x} & x\in(-1,\infty) \setminus \{0\}\end{cases}$$

What worked in similar problems was writing Taylor expansion of $g(x) = \log(x+1)$ at $0$ and then shifting it by one power of $x$, like:
$$\log(x+1) = \sum_{k=0}\frac{(x-0)^k}{k!}g^{(k)}(0),$$

where $g(x) = \log(x+1)$ and $g^{(k)}(0) = (-1)^{k+1}(k-1)!(x+1)^{-k}.$
Then $$\frac{\log(x+1)}{8!x} = \sum_{k=0}\frac{x^k}{k!}(-1)^{(k+1)}(k-1)!\frac{1}{8!x} = \\\sum_{k=0}\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\cdot8!}(k-1)!$$

Then given $t = k-1$ left part under sum would be $\frac{(x-0)^t}{t!}$ and right would be $f^{(t)}(0)$. But doing so we should change $\sum_{k=0}$ to $\sum_{t = -1}$ - it doesn't match Taylor expansion formula (summation should start at $0$ and I don't know what to do about that fact.

The right answer to the problem is: $f^{(7)}(0) = -1/64$,  $f^{(8)}(0) = 1/9$,  $f^{(9)}(0) = -9/10$,  $f^{(10)}(0) = 90/11$.

Comment: You probably meant $g^{(k)}$ where you typed $g^{(x)}$

Comment: The formula for $g^{(k)}(0)$ doesn't work for $k=0,$ only for $k>0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $f^{(0)}(x) = f(x)$, why doesn't it work?

Comment: $g (0)=\log 1=0.$ Your formula involves $(-1)!,$ which is undefined.

Comment: Because for $k = 0$, the formula gives $g^{(0)}(0) = (-1)^1 (-1)!$. This is not equal to $g(0) = 0$, or any other number because $(-1)! = \Gamma(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: The series expansion giving $\log(x+1)$ begins at $k=1$ since the constant term is null.

Comment: You have told us you substituted $j=k-1,$ but you never tell us either what you got after substituting, nor what the answer is supposed to be, so we are missing a lot of information.

Comment: $8!$ is there just for fun, its example exam question and I know that someone who writes the problems likes adding random number here and there. It's not important, I just included it to compare with the answer which is: $f^{(7)}(0) = -1/64$,  $f^{(8)}(0) = 1/9$,  $f^{(9)}(0) = -9/10$,  $f^{(10)}(0) = 90/11$.

Comment: Put the information in the question. A user should need to read comments to have complete information. What did you get after substituting, and what answer was given?

Comment: I think I understand know that for $k=0$ the formula is undefined, but still don't know how to handle that - I've never seen an example of function which gives undefined symbol when one try to write its Taylor expansion. I would be very grateful if someone could write the proper solution because I can't put it all together.

Comment: Well, the easiest way is to just note that $g(0) = 0$ and start your Taylor series at $k = 1$.

Comment: The function doesn't given an undefined value when $k=0.$ Your formula gives an undefined value. You can figure out the value when $k=0$ separately.

Comment: Your formula comes from induction starting at $k=1,$ so there was no reason to expect it to work for $k=0.$

Comment: @eyeballfrog So I can just write that $g(x) = \sum_{k=1}\frac{x^k}{k!}g^{(k)}(0)$ and then substituting $t = k-1$ gives $\sum_{t=0}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}n=\ln(x+1)$$

Therefore:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n-1}}n=\frac{\ln(x+1)}x$$

or

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{n-1}}{8!n}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^nn!}{8!(n+1)n!} =\frac{\ln(x+1)}{8!x}$$

in this [Interactive graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hzk7evlomz) and $f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{8!(n+1)}$ with derivatives from the Taylor series formula matching [yours](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=table%5B%28-1%29%5En+n%21%2F%288%21+%28n%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C10%7D%5D)